# Interoperability of NSOperationQueue and GCD

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, libdispatch

I am building a library for which I'd like the processing to happen in a single serial queue. Some of the APIs I use take [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/) (e.g. [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/)) and some take [`dispatch_queue_t`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) (e.g. [`CBCentralManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/)).

How do I specify the `NSOperationQueue` and `dispatch_queue_t` values so that they point to the same queue? Or are the two not interoperable and what I'm trying to do is not possible and/or advisable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `dispatch_queue_t` in the second case; assign it to the [`underlyingQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSOperationQueue/underlyingQueue) of an `NSOperationQueue` for the first. `NSOperationQueue`s sit atop dispatch queues; since iOS 8 you can specify the queue.